# Draw elevation shadows to canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-elevation

I use the code below to draw a view on to a bitmap/canvas.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    viewGroup.getWidth (), viewGroup.getHeight (), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
viewGroup.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
```

It works great, with one small problem: it doesn't draw elevation shadows. I assume that the shadows aren't drawn in the draw method. So where are they drawn and how can I transfer them to my canvas?

Comment: Were you able to solve somehow?

Answer (score 7):

No, shadows are drawn for Views at a lower level than that. You're using the software rendering pipeline which does not support shadows.

Comment: Is there anyway to access this 'lower level'?

Comment: Any way around this @Chris ?

Comment: This is a problem that has never seen a proper solution. To this day we still cannot easily convert a view to bitmap and keep its shadows, not even Pixel.copy api solved that, and the media projection option is not an option due to the consent prompt.